How can I get image keywords using PhotoKit on macOS?
I'm trying without success to get the custom keywords attached to images inside my Photos library on macOS.
I suppose they are in some way attached to a PHAsset, so I tried to get image metadata like this:
fileprivate extension PHAsset {
    func getMetaData() {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
        option.isSynchronous = true
        manager.requestImageDataAndOrientation(for: self, options: option) { data, uti, orientation, info in
            let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data! as CFData, nil)
            let imageMetaData = CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source!, 0, nil)
            print(imageMetaData)
        }

    }
}

I get a gazillion of metadata: {Exif}, {GPS}, TIFF and a strange {MakerApple} that I cannot understand, but my keywords are nowhere to be found. Maybe they are inside {IPTC} metadata that I cannot retrieve in any way?
I gave for granted that PHAsset metadata was the way to go, but probably I'm really wrong. It looks impossible, where should I look?
